Functions are found and ran when 'func start' command is entered, however functions are NOT recognised when commanding func azure publish
essentially I have a function that I'm trying to deploy to azure. When i type 'func start', the function runs locally and post requests can be sent to it. When I try and deploy my function to azure however, the deployment is always successful, yet the function itself is never pushed to azure. I.e.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-07-26T15:17:11.932Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in : ... (blank)...
Any ideas why I'm not seeing any errors thrown on the deployment end and the function isn't being recognized here? It's a very large project hence why I'm not providing code.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Provide your function code and local.settings.json.

Sometimes, though the function code deployment succeeds, it struggles to sync the trigger due to various reasons, refer article.
Test the functions locally before deploying to Azure and check if able to sync the trigger:

It could also be due to the modules required for the project are missing in requirements.txt
Check the function definition and the code to make sure the configuration is valid, Sync triggers issue occurs if there are any variables declared outside of the wrapped function.

Create a new sample python function project and compare your files and configurations with the sample function project.

Code Snippet:
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

The settings in local.setting.json should match the application settings of function app, especially AzureWebJobsStorage.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string(which function app uses)>"
  }
}


Azure function app might not be able to sync the latest code changes properly. Restart the Function App in the Azure portal to force a reload of the code changes.

